# Create a date from a list of numbers stored in a table

Tags: sql

I have a table that has stores the day and month of public holidays. I want to create dates from those numbers in SQL

```
ID   Day   Month     Name
1     1      1      New Years
2     9      8      Womens Day
3     25     12     Christmas Day
```

I want to list the dates as follows(using current year 2020)

```
1 Wednesday, New Years
9 Sunday, Womens Day
25 Friday, Christmas Day
```

Comment: which dbms (sql-server, mysql, oracle, postgresql, ...) you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution

```
SELECT concat(Day,' ', DATENAME(weekday,DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, 
  GETDATE()),Day, Month)),', ',Name) from Holiday
```

Output below here:

[image: output here]

Comment: Thank you, this method wasnt returning the entire list though

Comment: I have added one row for sample. Just rename holiday table with your table .you will get entire list.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(mDay, ' ', DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, 
  GETDATE()),mMonth, mDay)), ', ', Name)  
FROM MyTable
```

Where I have renamed the `Day` and `Month` fields to `mDay` and `mMonth` to avoid confusion with reserved words.

Table named `MyTable`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution on SQL-Server:

**SQL-Server before version 2012:**

```
SELECT CAST(Day AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' ' + DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(DATE, CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(Month AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(Day AS VARCHAR(2)), 23)) + ', ' + Name AS strDate
FROM holidays;
```

**SQL-Server since version 2012:**

```
SELECT CONCAT(Day, ' ', DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), Month, Day)), ', ', Name) AS strDate
FROM holidays;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bffc14b65fc9833b5e951aed39bbd3bc)

You can use the following solution on MySQL:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Day, ' ', DAYNAME(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(NOW()), Month, Day),'%Y-%m-%d')), ', ', Name) AS strDate
FROM holidays;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2691424f7e40d12d5237537c021b6a7d)